# Switch button - disable swipe function

Tags: android

I have a `switch` button (actually is a custom one) and I want to disable the swipe functionality for some reason; I want the user to be able to click it only. Is there a way to achieve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: May help this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753355/switch-between-doubletap-and-swipe

Comment: swipes (they are called FLING EVENTS) - i didn't knew that... I will try this in a minute

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can setClickable(false) to your Switch, then listen for the onClick() event within the Switch's parent and toggle it programmatically. The switch will still appear to be enabled but the swipe animation won't happen.

...

[In onCreate()]

```
Switch switchInternet = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_internet);
switchInternet.setClickable(false);
```

...

[click listener]

```
public void ParentLayoutClicked(View v){
    Switch switchInternet = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_internet);

    if (switchInternet.isChecked()) {
        switchInternet.setChecked(false);           
    } else {
        switchInternet.setChecked(true);    
    }       
}
```

...

[layout.xml]

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:onClick="ParentLayoutClicked"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Switch
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/switch_internet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="NOT CONNECTED"
            android:textOn="CONNECTED"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                                                
            android:text="@string/s_internet_status" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in this case it's not clickable at all, and you can't change checked status, author just asked about swipe

Answer (score 27):

A better way is to prevent the Switch class from receiving `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` events.

This can be done with:

```
switchButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
  }
});
```

Then you are free to set a click listener on the switch as appropriate.

Check out the [implementation of Switch](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/Switch.java#404) to see how dragging works. It's pretty cool!

Comment: It doesn't works. On click event doesn't appears. Switch still swiping.

Comment: Try `setClickable(false)` and implement `setOnTouchListener` in addition

Answer (score 13):

To disable a Switch use following method

```
switchBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

To make switch not clickable use

```
switchBtn.setClickable(false);
```

where switchBtn is Switch object

Comment: It doesn't works. First of all because on click event doesn't appears after we switchBtn.setEnabled(false). For second, for disabled view we have different resources.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is:

```
switchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
@Override           
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            //Your code
                }
                return true;            
    }       
});
```

Or ButterKnife:

```
@OnTouch(R.id.switchView)
public boolean switchStatus(Switch switchView, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // your code
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Good that you also added the ButterKnife flavor!

Answer (score 3):

You can custom a view that extends Switch then override its onTouchEvent()

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean handle = ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
    return handle ? handle : super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using binding adapters this can be done with this simple Kotlin extension:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@BindingAdapter("isSwipeEnabled")
fun SwitchCompat.setSwipeEnabled(isSwipeEnabled: Boolean) {
    setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (isSwipeEnabled)
            false
        else
            event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in a layout file like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        isSwipeEnabled="@{false}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
```

in `setOnTouchListener` will remove the drag effect to the switch

```
SwitchMaterial switchCamera = view.findViewById(R.id.switchCamera);

        switchCamera.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
        }
    });
switchCamera.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.switchCamera:
            //apply your logic here
             break;

         

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//This code works fine

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    Switch my_switch;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    my_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.my_switch);
    my_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.my_switch:
            if(my_switch.isChecked())
                my_switch.setChecked(true);                
            else           
                my_switch.setChecked(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

}