# How to disable swipe in switch compat?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I need to disable swipe in switch compat.I am using OnclickListener for toggling the switch.I have implemented some functionality for onClickListener.But when the user swipes the toggle he is not getting the implemented functionality.I need to disable swipe for switch compat.

Note: I am not using onCheckedlistener since I was getting some issues withonCheckedListener.

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
>     android:id="@+id/switchButton"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:checked="false"
>     android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>     android:text="Switch example"
>     />
> ```

---

> ```
> SwitchCompat switchCompat;
> switchCompat=(SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
>      switchCompat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "toggled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //added
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: @Aks4125 :That solution did not help me

Comment: Then you should mention in your question about research. As you can see below answer by AJ is identical from the same post. :)

Comment: Accepted answer is available in duplicate question. I am saying here because you said that question didn't solve your problem.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126040/4647628

Comment: You can do this switchBtn.isClickable = false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to prevent switch class from receiving swipe events by using the following code:

```
switchBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
    }
});
```

this may prevent the switch from receiving the swipe

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks , I want to perform action on OnClick , not on OnCheckChanged. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

use `TouchListener`

```
switchButton.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(p0: View, p1: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                when (p1.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        return false
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        return false
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                        return true
                    }
                    else -> {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

now you cant swipe switch