# How to display the inactive state of the on switch

Tags: java, android

I want to display inactive state when internet no connection, like on screen. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: `.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: good work, thank`s

Comment: I provided answear so you can accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch button - disable swipe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805188/switch-button-disable-swipe-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method:

```
public void setEnabled (boolean enabled)
```

on your view to archiv needed result.

**From documentation**:

> Set the enabled state of this view. The interpretation of the enabled
>   state varies by subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
make method for internet check ..

```
public  boolean isNetConnected() throws Throwable {
    boolean netConnected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService("connectivity");
    if (connectivity == null) {
        netConnected = false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < info.length; ++i) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    netConnected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "====isNetConnected====" + netConnected);
    return netConnected;
}
```

and xml for switch..

```
      <Switch
            android:id="@+id/swPush"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

after that check like this way..

```
        if (isNetConnected()){
        swPush.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        swPush.setChecked(false);
    }
```