# How can I programmatically enable and disable a switch in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to programmatically change the ***enabled*** state of the Switch control (preferrably using the SwitchCompat class). Changing the state is something that is easy to do in the Layout Editor of Android Studio, but I would like to change it in response to an event in code. I found that I was not able to set the ***enabled*** attribute in code.

The closest question and answers that I found on Stackoverflow:
[Switch button - disable swipe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805188/switch-button-disable-swipe-function)

Although the **setEnabled()** method exists in the [Button class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) (under Inherited Methods > android.view.View), it does not appear to extend to the [Switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) and [SwitchCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SwitchCompat) classes. I suspected that it was a decision made by Google devs about accessibility, but I have not been able to find anything online to back this theory up.

Comment: Did you try with .toggle() ?

Comment: or with `setChecked(bool)`

Comment: *Enabled* state, not checked state. As in greyed-out, and unresponsive to clicks / presses when disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading one of Yogesh's answers, I have refined it to include the ability to toggle the enabled state. The following examples assumes that one button and one switch has been placed on an activity.

**Java:**

```
// This line appears either just inside the Activity class, or outside of it
public static Boolean switch1Enabled = true;

// This block appears in the onCreate() function of the Activity class
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Switch switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
// Button listener used to simulate change event
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch1Enabled = !switch1Enabled;
        switch1.isClickable = switch1Enabled;
        switch1.alpha = (switch1Enabled ? 1.0f : 0.5f);
    }
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
// This line appears either just inside the Activity class, or outside of it
var switch1Enabled: Boolean = true

// This block appears in the onCreate() function of the Activity class
val button1: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
val switch1: Switch = findViewById(R.id.switch1)
// Button listener used to simulate change event
button1.setOnClickListener{
    switch1Enabled = !switch1Enabled
    switch1.isClickable = switch1Enabled
    switch1.alpha = if (switch1Enabled) 1.0f else 0.5f
}
```

The boolean value should be set to the initial enabled state of the switch control. In this example, the control is already enabled in the layout editor, so the `switch1Enabled` variable is set to `true`.

I am still perplexed as to why the enabled attribute is not available with this control in code. I will up-vote whoever can answer why.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Switch mySwitch = findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

// Check if the Switch is enabled
boolean isEnabled = mySwitch.isEnabled();

// Update the enable state of the Switch
mySwitch.setClickable(!isEnabled);
mySwitch.setAlpha(isEnabled ? 0.5f : 1.0f);
```

Comment: Not bad. The only problem with this is that if you change the enabled state once, and then tried to change the state again, the state is not being stored from the first change, thus the state would not be updated. This could probably be fixed by including a global variable that keeps the current enabled state of the switch.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me

@BindView(R.id.Switch_Availabilty)
Switch SwitchAvailabilty;

```
if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
   SwitchAvailabilty.setChecked(true);
  } else {
     SwitchAvailabilty.setChecked(false);
 }
```

If You are still getting Error please describe your error with code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am after the programmatic change of the *enabled* state, not the checked state.